# What's the measure of the segment $CG$ in question below?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: In a circumference of diameter $CE$,the strings $BE$ and $AC$ intersect at $F$ and the diameter $BD$ intercepts $AC$ in $G$.
Calculate $GC$. If $AF = 3 , FG = 2$ and $AC = BE$

My progress:
It seems to me little data... I don't know if it's possible to solve it with just this information

I find : T. Menelaus: $\triangle BOE-AC\\
EF.BG.OC=FB.GO.\underbrace{EC}_{2OC} \rightarrow EF.BE = 2FB.GP $

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ \small \triangle CBE \cong \triangle EAC$,  as both are right triangles and one of their sides and their hypotenuse are equal. That leads to $ \small \triangle CFE$ being isosceles with $ \small CF = FE \implies BF = AF = 3$.

Apply Menelaus's theorem in $ \small \triangle CEF$ with traversal $ \small OB$ intersecting sides $ \small CE$ and $ \small CF$.

$ \displaystyle \small \frac{EB}{BF} \cdot \frac{FG}{GC} \cdot \frac{CO}{OE} = 1 ~ ​\implies \displaystyle \small \frac{EB}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{GC} = 1$

Using $ \small EB = AC, ~ 2 AC = 3 GC \implies 2 (GC + 5) = 3 GC$

$\therefore  \small GC =10$

Comment: Grateful...I used the Menelaus in the wrong triangle

Answer (score 2):

Consider the image with the fact that $\small \triangle CBE\cong\triangle EAC\ (\because AC=BE)$.

[image: img]

$\small{\triangle OCG\sim\triangle FBG}\implies\displaystyle{\frac3r=\frac2b}\implies 3b=2r$

From sine rule to $\small \triangle OCG$,
$\dfrac{a}{\sin2x}=\dfrac b{\sin x}\implies a=2b\cos x\tag1$

From right triangle $\small CAE\to CA=CE\cos x\\$ $a+5=2r\cos x=3b\cos x\tag2$

$\frac{(1)}{(2)}$,$$\frac a{a+5}=\frac 23\implies \boxed{a=10}$$

Comment: Image not to scale, but the result is confirmed via geogebra.

Comment: Yes that's correct. I get the same by Menelaus's

Comment: Good exit by trigonometry...thank you..correct answer